# Problem with migration of Community

Tags: community, salesforcedx, deployment

I try to migrate Community between 2 dev org. I got error

> Your site needs a route with route type top-articles. Update your file
> and try again.

I prepared everything according to this manual :

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm&type=5

Im not using a scratch org but i using sfdx to do that

this is my package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomSite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ExperienceBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Network</name>
    </types>
    <version>53.0</version>
</Package>
```

im using `sfdx force:source:deploy -x "./manifest/package.xml" -c --verbose --apiversion 53.0`

Site is not relevant in that migration when i exclude a SiteDotCom and Site i got same error.

Package.xml without sites :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ExperienceBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Network</name>
    </types>
    <version>53.0</version>
</Package>
```

Communities are just created without any modification. Maybe someone know how to handle that problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable experience bundle metadata on both orgs?

Comment: Of course experience is enabled  everything is prepared for migration

Comment: Please [edit] the question to enumerate the preparation done and to explain why CustomSite is relevant in this migration. As it stands you have not provided enough information and hence my initial question. Other questions could be raised where you think it obvious that you have done it, but where you do not state it.

Comment: sure, i updated my question. thanks

Comment: OK, so the question is much improved. Can you run a search across your metadata (after retrieving from the one org) for "top-articles". It sounds like there is a view for it but no route, which implies an incomplete/corrupt retrieve.